# Kendo: Getting a Model posted back from a grid row

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Using **Kendo** UI Grid in **MVC 4**:

I am trying to put a "**Edit**" button and "**Delete**" button that will post the model for the row to a controller and action. The Grid should act like a simple list that has an edit and delete button.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyViewModel>()
  .Name("Grid")
  .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(p => p.UserLoginId);
          columns.Bound(p => p.AppUserName);
          columns.Bound(p => p.AppUserStatus);
           *** EDIT BUTTON HERE to post row's MyViewModel to new Controller/action ***
           *** DELETE BUTTON HERE to post row's MyViewModel to new Controller/action***

      })
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
           .Ajax()
           .Read(read => read.Action("SearchUser_Read", "Search"))
  ))
```

How would I add these two buttons to each row so that the Grid posted the model to the controller / action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible only through Ajax. Because even if you surround the Grid with a **form** tag the form could only post to a single action, you cannot post to different actions depending on the submit button you pressed.

I suggest you to use the standard approaches to Edit the Grid - [InLine](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-inline.html), [Popup](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-popup.html) and [InCell](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing.html) modes.

Or if you want to POST with form submit (without Ajax) to the server use the ServerBinding (like shown in the offline demos) and in the [Documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/server-editing).

Comment: I only wish to basically open an editor in a new controller with the ID or the model of the row. Is this not possible?

Comment: Open an editor is what @Pechka mentions as the Popup editing. Here you have two buttons for `updating` and `canceling` changes. If you click on `updating` then your `DataSource` `transport.update` function is invoked. Is this `transport.update` not enough? I think it is since it can be any JavaScript code (or just the URL of your controller).

Comment: It is possible, you do not need to do POST in that case. For example you could create a Template column with a hyperlink that will navigate the user to the Home/UpdatePerson action. You will pass the  id (in this case personID) so you can use it in the controller and return the object you want to edit and pass it as model to the editing view.

columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<a href='"+ Url.Action("UpdateAction","Home")+ "?personID=#=PersonID#'" +">Click to go and edit Person</a>");